# NGINX - Return 301 vs Rewrite

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, return

I use [**NGINX**](http://nginx.org/) in my dedicated server.

I've a question about the **return** and **rewrite 301**.

---

**Rewrite 301:**

```
rewrite ^ http://xxx.xxxxx.net/xx-xxx/$request_uri? permanent;
```

**Return 301:**

```
location ~ redirect-this/?$ {
    return 301 http://xxx.xxxxx.net/xx-xxx/redirect-this$1;
}
```

---

All redirects work correctly. But..

**Which is the most effective method to make a 301 redirect?**

I've more than 200 url to redirect. So, what you recommend?

Comment: This question is a little bit confusing since you are comparing `rewrite ^` (match anything) with `location ~ redirect-this/?$` which matches a specific regex. You should reformulate it. But anyway a good question... I'm curious which one is faster `rewrite ^/test` or `location ^/test` with if.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As stated in the [nginx pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites) you should use server blocks and `return` statements as they're way faster than evaluating RegEx via `location` blocks.

Since you're forcing the rewrite rule to send a 301 there's no difference when it comes to SEO, btw..

Comment: So what you are suggesting is in fact , return 301 directly in the server block? e.g `server { server_name foo.com; return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri; }` ?

Comment: @tutuDajuju I'd suggest that you use `return 301 http://$host$request_uri;` vs `$server_name` as this will result in redirecting to the first defined server_name opposed to the host in which it was intended.