# NGINX rewrite location to another port

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location, proxypass

Have installed NGINX so I can divert

```
http://example.com/Dev/ to http://example.com:8080/apex/f?p=4550:1
```

I thought I found the solution and gave it a go:

Changed ngnix.config

```
   location /dev/ {
       rewrite ^/(/dev/)(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/apex/$1 break;
       rewrite_log on;
    }
```

.

```
sudo systemctrl reload nginx
```

But when I try http://example.com/Dev/ on a browser

I get the 500 error.

Website is listening to 8080 and NGiNX listening to 80

Also tried

```
location /dev {
    rewrite ^/dev(.*) /apex/$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Comment: What's in the logs for an exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit [return 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165746/nginx-return-301-vs-rewrite)

After reading the above answer I tried using return instead of rewrite  and it worked.

Anyway here is what worked.

```
location ~ /dev/?$ {
        return 302 http://example.com:8080/apex/$1;
     }
```

After playing around I also got it to work with rewrite looks like I just needed to add a '~' in the location line

```
location ~ /dev {
           rewrite ^/dev(.*) http://example.com:8080/apex$1 last;
        }
```

Comment: Can anyone please explain what the '~' after the location command as it seemed to make the difference?

Comment: AndrewT: "If a tilde modifier is present, this location will be interpreted as a case-sensitive regular expression match." See [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)