# Nginx use subdomain as query parameter and rewrite URL

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to use subdomains as query parameter on the domain itself.
An example would be the following:

I want nginx to take **ab.example.com** and call **example.com?key=ab**, now the backend will return a specific config, which should be used for the subdomain "**ab**".

Afterwards the user should see the content (logo branding to be precise) of **example.com?key=ab** but in the client's URL field the **ab.example.com** should persist.

And all further requests should show for example **ab.example.com/login** instead of **example.com/login**.

I hope that what I have said is sufficiently understandable. I have tried various examples from the internet and tried to find some hints.

The nginx file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com *.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/certs/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/keys/ssl.key;

    root /var/www/example_site;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        error_page 404 =200;
    }
}
```

I have already tried to map, but it redirects to a wrong domain:

```
map $host $subdomain {
    ~^(?<sub>.+)\.example\.com$ $sub;
}
```

And tried adding a static if statement in the server block, too:

```
if ($host = "ab.example.com") {
    rewrite . ?key=ab;
}
```

An additional server block did not help either:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.ab.example.come ab.example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://example.com/?key=ab permanent;
}
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or what part of the documentation I should read again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do it inside your own `server_name` directive. You can assign a variable in a regexp directly there. If you need a different behavior for `www.` subdomain just remove `*.example.com` from the block and add this one in another file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com$; 
    return       301 http://example.com$request_uri?key=$subdomain;
}
```

Note that I didn't use `rewrite`, which you shouldn't need. Using `return` [performs better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167926/3399504). `301` stands for the kind of redirect. And then, you use your `server_name` assigned variable to redirect where you need.

Comment: using `return 301 https://$host$request_uri?key=$subdomain;`instead of `return 301 http://example.com$request_uri?key=$subdomain;` works. But to make it reload save after redirection to https one need to put some logic inside the _https server block_, right?

Comment: Sure! If you are struggling with that too, open another question and link it on a comment